# I can't scroll the entire screen

Tags: flutter

When I slide the Expanded(child: MusicListCardWidget()) part of the screen from the widgets in the column, the widgets at the top do not slide, but the entire screen needs to slide at once. How can I do this?

When I slide the Expanded(child: MusicListCardWidget()) part of the screen from the widgets in the column, the widgets at the top do not slide, but the entire screen needs to slide at once. How can I do this?

```
  Scaffold(
      body: Column(
    
      children: [
         SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
       Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text("En son", style: TextStyles.plyListTextStyle(context)),
          SizedBox(width: 2.w,),
          Icon(Icons.auto_awesome_motion_rounded)
        ],
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
      Container(
        //width: 60.h,
        height: 30.h,
       // color: Colors.black,
        child: PageView(
          controller: controller,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
          ,children: [
            MusicCardWidget(),
            MusicCardWidget()  
          ],
        )
        ),
        Expanded(child: MusicListCardWidget()),
    ],
  ),
);


 class _MusicListCardWidgetState extends State<MusicListCardWidget> {
  @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return  Padding(
   padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 17.sp),
    child: ListView.builder(
     itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       return ListTile(
 
          title: Text('.', style: 
         TextStyles.musicListCardTextStyle(context),),
          subtitle: Text('.'),
          leading: ClipRRect(
             borderRadius : BorderRadius.circular(10)
            ,child: Image.asset('images/', fit: BoxFit.cover ,)),
          trailing: IconButton(icon: Icon( 
           Icons.play_circle_outline_outlined), onPressed: () {
            
          },),

       );
     },
  ),
);
```

}
}

Comment: Can you post some graphics of the current and the desired behaviour?

Comment: @AlejandroCumpa When I scroll the screen from top to bottom, half of it scrolls and the other half does not scroll. I want the entire screen to slide from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Use a SingleChildScrollView:

```
        Scaffold(
              body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 2.h,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Text("En son", style: TextStyles.plyListTextStyle(context)),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 2.w,
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.auto_awesome_motion_rounded)
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 2.h,
                    ),
                    Container(
                        //width: 60.h,
                        height: 30.h,
                        // color: Colors.black,
                        child: PageView(
                          controller: controller,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          children: [MusicCardWidget(), MusicCardWidget()],
                        )),
    /// in case the error persists, either change the code of MusicListCardWidget 
/// to a widget without vertical scroll like a Column instead of Listview, 
/// or put a Container with a delimited Height around it
                    MusicListCardWidget(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
```

Comment: When I do what you said, I get this error: RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: it is probably the expanded. I have modified a little bit, but I can't test it because you have custom widgets.

Comment: when you have already a scroll, don't put expanded inside in the vertical

Comment: And you probably will have to revise MusicListCartWidget to use a Column instead of a ListView( or a scroll type widget). Or, put a height limit around it, but that would be weird.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to scroll up-down, you'll need a Scrollable view, but it will conflict with the expanded, because it would try to expand to the infinity,
Adding a `SingleChildScrollView` and removing the expanded, should look like this:

```
    Scaffold(
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: 
          body: Column(    
          children: [
             SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
           Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("En son", style: TextStyles.plyListTextStyle(context)),
              SizedBox(width: 2.w,),
              Icon(Icons.auto_awesome_motion_rounded)
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 2.h,),
          Container(       
            height: 30.h,       
            child: PageView(
              controller: controller,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal
              ,children: [
                MusicCardWidget(),
                MusicCardWidget()  
              ],
            )
            ),                 
      MusicListCardWidget(),
    ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I get this error RenderPhysicalModel object was given an infinite size during layout.

Comment: What type of widget is teh MusicLIstCardWiget ?

Comment: I added the MusicLIstCardWiget widget to the question

Comment: Thank you for your time, problem solved @Alejandro cumpa

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you with what you want. Instead of using Column use ListView Widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleWidget> createState() => _ExampleWidgetState();
}

class _ExampleWidgetState extends State<ExampleWidget> {
  PageController controller = PageController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 2),
          const Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text("En son",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black)),
              SizedBox(width: 2),
              Icon(Icons.auto_awesome_motion_rounded)
            ],
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 2),
          SizedBox(
              // width: size.width * .6,
              height: size.height * 0.08,
              // color: Colors.black,
              child: PageView(
                onPageChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                controller: controller,
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: const [
                  MusicCardWidget(text: 'Music Card 1', color: Colors.orange),
                  MusicCardWidget(
                    text: 'Music Card 2',
                    color: Colors.blueAccent,
                  )
                ],
              )),
          const Expanded(child: MusicListCardWidget()),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MusicListCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MusicListCardWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 15,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        primary: false,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Card(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
              elevation: 15,
              child: Center(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Card: ${index.toString()}",
                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MusicCardWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color color;

  const MusicCardWidget({super.key, required this.text, required this.color});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color,
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                text,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style:
                    const TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
              ),
            ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```